# access wt on amazon ec2 with elastic ip

Tags: amazon-ec2, wt

I source-compiled the latest wt on a micro instance of ec2 with ubuntu running
when I lunch one of the examples:

```
1:23:15.~/progs/wt-3.2.3-rc1/examples/widgetgallery
>../../build/examples/widgetgallery/widgetgallery.wt --docroot . --http-address localhost --http-port 8080
[2012-Oct-25 01:23:16.898953] 969 - [info] "config: reading Wt config file: /etc/wt/wt_config.xml (location = '../../build/examples/widgetgallery/widgetgallery.wt')"
[2012-Oct-25 01:23:16.901653] 969 - [info] "WServer/wthttp: initializing built-in wthttpd"
[2012-Oct-25 01:23:16.902948] 969 - [info] "wthttp: started server: http://localhost:8080"
```

I can't access it when i put `http://54.243.50.12:8080/` or `http://54.243.50.12/` into chrome's address bar. It keeps loading and never finds it.

Associating of the elastic IP worked. I can connect to 54.243.50.12 with putty.

If I try to specify the elastic IP when I start wt, the wt server doesn't start:

```
1:31:45.~/progs/wt-3.2.3-rc1/examples/widgetgallery
>../../build/examples/widgetgallery/widgetgallery.wt --docroot . --http-address 54.243.50.12 --http-port 8080
[2012-Oct-25 01:31:53.696951] 1056 - [info] "config: reading Wt config file: /etc/wt/wt_config.xml (location = '../../build/examples/widgetgallery/widgetgallery.wt')"
[2012-Oct-25 01:31:53.699035] 1056 - [info] "WServer/wthttp: initializing built-in wthttpd"
[2012-Oct-25 01:31:53.699968] 1056 - [error] "wthttp: Error occurred when binding to 54.243.50.12:8080
bind: Cannot assign requested address"
[2012-Oct-25 01:31:53.700614] 1056 - [info] "WServer/wthttp: fatal: Error (asio): bind: Cannot assign requested address"
1:31:53.~/progs/wt-3.2.3-rc1/examples/widgetgallery
>
```

Without an elastic IP, it was the same story.

the 8080 port is open:

```
>netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I did all that is in http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/boards/2/topics/4484#message-4516 but it didn't help.

Comment: this question was closed on serverfault as too narrow. there is a similar question for django http://serverfault.com/questions/430848/amazon-ec2-not-able-to-open-web-application-even-if-port-it-opened, wt is an equivalent of django. it's the same as closing gentoo question because it's more narrow than MS windows. there was no way of leaving a comment there but i wanted to point it out so i'm leaving it here.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to open a port in Security Group > Inbound